# fullcalendar json data only selected values

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have this code within my fullcalendar options:

```
  events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      var source = [{}];
      $.ajax({
          url: "/api/v1/eventjobs?tipo=4",
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization:
              "Bearer XcsxcTYXjSW_kHCXgvAWfRC-GYlP0-WyvVOy4Z0jpfo",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {
              $(response).each(function (e, v) { 
                source.push({
                  title: type_damage+' '+first_name+' '+last_name,
                  start: date_event,
                  color: '#25427e'
                });
              });

            // console.log(source);
            successCallback(source);
          }
      });
  }
```

But I have an error with the

```
source.push({
  title: type_damage+' '+first_name+' '+last_name,
  start: date_event,
  color: '#25427e'
});
```

Because my console says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: type_damage is not defined

Comment: As it says in the error, you didn't define the variable type_damage. What is value of type_damage, you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

`type_damage`, `first_name`, `last_name` and `date_event` are not defined anywhere. I'm guessing they're supposed to come from the response you're looping through.

Therefore you need to reference them as properties of the object in the current iteration of the loop, for example:

```
$(response).each(function (e, v) { 
  source.push({
    title: v.type_damage + ' ' + v.first_name + ' ' + v.last_name,
    start: v.date_event,
    color: '#25427e'
  });
});
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/each/

---

Also this:

```
var source = [{}];
```

needs to be

```
var source = [];
```

otherwise you'll end up with a pointless empty object at the start of your array.